# Iteration to create createCriteria. Getting error org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table of images, each having a many to many relationship to a table of galleries. I'm trying to use a `org.hibernate.Criteria` to return all images that are linked a given list of galleries.

I have been trying the following, where I loop over the list of galleries and create a new `createCriteria` for each (e.g. one inner join per required gallery), this works with just one gallery. However when I try multiple I get a `org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: galleries` error...

ImagesDAOCustom.java

```
public Images getRandomImagesInGallerys(String[] galleryList) {             
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Images.class, "image");
        // We want an image that is part of all galleries so we need to create
        // a join per gallery.
        for (String gallery: galleryList) {
            criteria.createCriteria("image.galleries", gallery);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(gallery + ".name",gallery));
        }
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")));
        List<Integer> imageIdList = criteria.list();

        Images result;
        if (imageIdList.size() > 0) {
            int index = rand.nextInt(imageIdList.size());
            result = imagesDAO.findOne(imageIdList.get(index));
        } else {
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Images.java

```
public class Images  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ugc_images_id")
    private int id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="ugc_image_galleries", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="image_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="gallery_id")})
    private Set<Galleries> galleries = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

Galleries.java

```
public class Galleries }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ugc_galleries_id")
    private int id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="galleries")    
    private Set<Images> images = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    ...

}
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55082981/4808122) a workaround using `SqlRestriction` with `exists`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem and i search for hours and hours.

Here is what worked for me :

```
public Images getRandomImagesInGallerys(String[] galleryList) {

    String query = "from Images ";
    boolean first = true;

    for(String string : galleryList) {
        if(first){
            query+="where '"+string+"' member of galleries ";
            first=false;
        } else {
            query+="or '"+string+"' member of galleries ";
        }
    }

    entityManager.createQuery(query, Images.class).getResultList();
}
```

Hope it help someone.